# JSON.parse() for an Object of type application/octet-stream

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON stream of type `application/octet-stream`. I need to parse this using `JSON.parse()` or similar? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

`application/octet-stream` is the MIME type for "Uh, I dunno, it's some bytes".

Either you have JSON which hasn't been correctly labelled and you can simply use `JSON.parse` as normal or you have something else and you need to identify what it is and why you have it.

This could be anything from "It is gzipped JSON that you need to gunzip before parsing as JSON" to "It is corrupted nonsense and you need to fix whatever is generating it".